# Why didn't Captain Pike say his background with religion after asking the others in New Eden?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, religion

In *Star Trek Discovery* episode ["New Eden"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8282868/) we see [Captain Pike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Pike_(Star_Trek)) ask [Joann Owosekun](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Joann_Owosekun) and [Michael Burnham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Burnham) what their background with religion is.

Joann says she grew up in a Luddite community which had no religious beliefs.

Michael Burnham says she is familiar with Earth's religious texts. She says this as if to say that religion is illogical.

There is an implied place for Captain Pike to say what his background is, but he skips over this and gets on with it. So we don't know what his background is.

Later when interacting with the religious community, he says:

> Peace be with you

and the community responds

> And also with you

which makes an implication about Captain Pike's religious background.

Normally this phrase is used in [Episcopalian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episcopal_Church_(United_States)) ([Anglican](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglicanism)) liturgies.

My question is: **Why didn't Captain Pike say his background with religion after asking the others in New Eden?**

Comment: The phrase is also used commonly in Roman Catholic, Lutheran, Orthodox, and many other liturgical Christian faiths, so it's not really just an Episcopalian/Anglican thing.

Comment: not to mention the phrase is quite commonly a greeting in Arabic / Muslim faith communities as well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He wasn't asking them about their religion idly.  He wanted to know how much they knew about religion and what they thought of it to determine whether they'd be useful or a hindrance when dealing with the locals who were very, very religious.  The reason why he didn't share his religious background if any is because they had no need to know it.  He was the one calling shots.  They weren't.

Comment: Oh, and the reason he said "Peace be with you" is because he'd given their holy book the once-over.  It has nothing to do with his religious background.